# What is the point of arranging (1/2,0) spinor into Majorana spinor?

Tags: field-theory, representation-theory, fermions, spinors, majorana-fermions

Using Srednicki's notation:

For a massive left-handed spinor $\psi$:

$\mathcal{L}=i\psi^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi-{1\over 2}m\psi\psi-{1\over 2} m\psi^{\dagger}\psi^{\dagger}$

It can be arranged into a Majorana spinor $\Psi \equiv \begin{pmatrix}\psi_c \\ \psi^{\dagger \dot{c}}\end{pmatrix}$

so that the Lagrangian has a more compact form:

$\mathcal{L}={i\over 2}\overline{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Psi-{1\over 2}m\overline{\Psi}\Psi$

This compact form requires an additional constraint: $\Psi=\mathcal{C}\overline{\Psi}^{T}$

which isn't very convenient.

The physics is the same. Only the notation differs. Despite the similarity with Dirac spinors, using Majorana spinors for (1/2,0) theory only obscure the physics. Why don't we quantize using the original form?

Comment: Please indicate why you downvoted.

Comment: I didn't, but I really should. A Dirac spinor is made up of two Majorana spinors. What obscure physics do you want illuminated? Have you gone through the related questions?

Comment: @CosmasZachos by Majorana spinor I meant the Dirac spinor for Majorana Fermions. And as far as I'm concerned, what you call Majorana spinors are called left-handed and right handed Weyl spinors.

Comment: In 4D you cannot have spinors simultaneously Majorana and Weyl. I'm sure the Related questions & answers would help...

Comment: @CosmasZachos If one expands Majorana Fermion into two components field, the Lagrangian is equivalent to the one for a single left-handed Weyl spinor. (from Srednicki section 36)

Comment: So you can map Weyl spinors to Majorana spinors, which however can be massive ... Sorry, I'm decoupling from the chitchat.

Comment: @CosmasZachos No need for sarcasm. It should be a difference in terminology. Just check Srednicki section 36.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I've added formulas and details

Answer (score 0):

The Majorana spinor is not the same as a Dirac spinor and (in 4 dimensions) cannot be simultaneously imposed when working with a Weyl spinor.

The requirement that a Dirac spinor equal its charge conjugate reduces the number of degrees of freedom by a factor of 2 and is effectively a reality condition for spinors.  The main difference is that if you were to go and compute the usual charge operator for a theory constrained by a Majorana condition you would find that you would have a particle that is: neutral, allowed to be massive that, and is its own antiparticle (this is not always a requirement for neutral particles).  In 4d neither Weyl nor Dirac fermions can have these qualities and so the Majorana fermion is truly something different, not just a different way to write things.

Comment: Have you checked the two lagrangian I wrote？They are equivalent. A majorana is equivalent to a massive （1/2，0）spinor

Comment: They are not equivalent.  The "arrangement into a Majorana spinor" you are doing is more than just a relabeling.  Imposing that condition on the spinor restricts its degrees of freedom.  This is is going to restrict things like the mode expansion of the field which will alter the physics as I stated.